# How to add my own classes in iReport when I change from Groovy to Java language?

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm working with *iReport* and *JasperReports*, when I began to do my report, *iReport* by default use *Groovy*, but I need to change to  *Java* (constrains in my job), I make my report with *Groovy* and It's works perfectly but when I change to *Java* language, I get a trouble, because I use a class(fields from java of a class) in my report, so the Mistake is: `myfield cannot be resolved  or is not a field.`

The class that I use to do my report is:

```java
public final class GrupoEstadistico implements Serializable {

    private Estadistico ccDocumento;
    private Estadistico ccNombres;

    //another class that is an attribute of type Estadistico

    private Date periodo;
    private String tipoEntidad;

    //and another primitives atributes: strings, int

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is the *Estadistico* class:

```java
public final class Estadistico implements Serializable, Comparable<Estadistico> {

    private String nombreEntidad;
    private int codigo;
    private int numeroConsultas = 0;

    //and aother primitives atributes: strings, int
    //getters and setters
}
```

And I use all attributes of the class *GrupoEstadistico* in my report like a fields.

And I use expressions to get the values of each *Estadistico* like:

```
$F{ccDocumento}.numeroConsultasanyone
```

The trouble that I get when I try to compile the report is:

```
numeroConsultas cannot be resolved  or is not a field.
```

What I understand is happening is:

- *iReport* not find my class attributes thus this has
- *iRreport* not understand the expressions I use.

This is that I been tried to solve my problem:

1. add a jar file with the classes required to classpath of *iReport*.
2. add the import like: `reporte.model.GruoEstadistico` in the properties of my report.
3. And I been edited the *xml* and I add the tag scriptlet:

```xml
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
 name="ListaConsultaEstadistico" pageWidth="895" pageHeight="595" 
 orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="855" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" 
 topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" 
 scriptletClass="reporte.model.GrupoEstadistico" 
 uuid="b0990d7b-fade-4200-a2ef-fb0416f5a9c2">
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm calling my report from the *Java* code the following way:

```java
/**Create a List of GrupoEstadistico class. */

List<GrupoEstadistico> this.dataSource = new ArrayList<GrupoEstadistico>();

/**Fill my List....*/


JasperPrint jasperPrint= JasperFillManager.fillReport( reportPath,this.parametros,
                 new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( this.dataSource ));
```

The dataSource is a  `List<GrupoEstadistico>`

But still does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try call public getter $F{ccDocumento}.getNumeroConsultas()

Comment: @Nicolai, thanks but not works, when I try to call the getter I get: `The method getNumeroConsultas() is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: How do you send ccDocumento in template?

Comment: Which class have field $F{ccDocumento} in jrxml? Is it java.lang.Object? 

  "The method getNumeroConsultas() is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: And scriptlet is not need for you. Define only fields ccDocumento, ccNombres, etc... in jrxml.  And check getters for this members of class

Comment: @sanBez Thanks for answer my questions, so I've a List of my class `GrupoEstadistico` and it's has a field ccDocumento(another class of type `Estadistico`). I send from java to jrxml the dataSource(List) , so it's possible get access to the atrubute of  the attribute?, or I needed to be very especific and only get the primitive attribute of a class?, I mean I try to get a `object->object->primitiveAttribute`, or I can just do `object->primitiveAttribute`.   I hope  you understand me.

Comment: Show definition field ccDocumento in jrxml

Answer (score 1):

Send your object in ireport using java program. Define a field with name of your instance and attribute. e.g.
Suppose you send your class instance with grupoEstadistico, define a field in ireport with name "grupoEstadistico.tipoEntidad". and Drag a textfield in any band. 
**RightClick->Edit Expression-> remove ${field}-> double click on your field->click apply**
It will add you attribute in **iReport **. now if you download your file as pdf format , it will show data what ever you send in this instance.

Comment: 1. Send your object in ireport using java program.  
Topicstarter send JRBeanCollection as DataSource  
2. grupoEstadistico.tipoEntidad  
What is grupoEstadistico? This fields don't present in DataSource.  It is object which don't must be present in fields of jrxml.  
  
Don't confuse author, please

Comment: @user1791574, Hi, the way in your does the things works,  but you  define all attributes,  I try to define the class of the class that have  the attribute because is too long(about the 50 fields) and when I used the *Groovy* it's works the expressions, but When I use Java, the expressions does not work.

Comment: For sending somefield you can make a class in which you can define some selected attribute and send it as as object. It provide you freedom to send some selected field.